# How to set height for UL using Jquery for below scenario

Tags: jquery, html, css

Below the HTML structure where i would like to find the height of the ul and set the max height to all both the ul. Below is the code i have used to set height. But for me its setting as 0 for both the UL. How to set the max height to both the UL. In css have given .col-sm-2.list-unstyled as float:left also.

## HTML

```
  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
        <!-- Content container to add padding -->
        <div class="yamm-content">
            <div class="row">
                <ul class="col-sm-2 list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                        <a href="/residential/en/us/about/">About Carrier</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/residential/en/us/about/corevalues/">Core Values</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/residential/en/us/about/fact-sheet/">Fact Sheet</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/residential/en/us/about/willis-carrier/">Willis Carrier</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/residential/en/us/about/history/">Carrier History</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

                <ul class="promotions-block menupromotion col-sm-2 list-unstyled hidden-xs">
                    <li class="holder col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-4">
                        <div class="promo_wrpr">
                            <a class="inpage-module-link" href="http://www.naturalleader.com" target="_blank">
                                <section class="promo_img_hldr">
                                    <img src="demo/img/natural-leadership-sustainability-utc-82x76.jpg"
                                         title="Learn about Natural Leadership and Sustainability at United Technologies Corporation"
                                         alt="Learn about Natural Leadership and Sustainability at United Technologies Corporation"
                                         class="img-responsive">
                                </section>
                                <div class="promo-text">
                                    <h3>
                                        <strong>NATURAL LEADERSHIP</strong>
                                    </h3>
                                    <span class="common-cta rightarrow">
                                        Learn about sustainability
                                        <span class="link-2liner">
                                        </span>
                                    </span>
                                </div>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

## JS part

```
 var b = $(".col-sm-2.list-unstyled").length;
        var c=0;        
        $(".col-sm-2.list-unstyled").each(function() {
                 if ($(this).height() > c) {
                c = $(this).height()
            }
        }); 
        for (var a = 0; a < b; a++) {
        $(".col-sm-2.list-unstyled").eq(a).removeAttr("style")
            $(".col-sm-2.list-unstyled").eq(a).height(c)
        }
```

Please help me out to set height. Thanks in advance

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: can you please post a fiddle link to reproduce your problem. That would be so much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest use jquery for this purpose. it is very simple and works like a charm
Get the height of the main ul; I'm guessing that is the .list-unstyled ul; and assign it to a variable.
then you can use jQuery to assign the ul height using the variable.

```
                        jQuery(document).ready(function() { 

                                    var setHeight = $(".list-unstyled").height();
                                    $(".promotions-block").height(setHeight);
                                    }
                                    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me : http://plnkr.co/edit/ncQ97aQOLXBSY0QBeMW9?p=preview

Both divs are set to same height.

```
var b = $(".col-sm-2.list-unstyled").length;
var c = 0;
$(".col-sm-2.list-unstyled").each(function() {
  if ($(this).height() > c) {
    c = $(this).height()
  }
});
for (var a = 0; a < b; a++) {
  $(".col-sm-2.list-unstyled").eq(a).height(c)
}
```

Comment: For me its setting height as 0

Comment: Check the Plnkr link provided. Try replacing your code with the one in plnkr, may be a typo somewhere. Both the ul are set to height 203px. Also check in console if you are getting any error.